# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined (line 115, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a script that notifies you in the line app but I can't seem to put a link in the message. When I tried to write the script just as instructed it goes`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined`  my link is not in the form . I made another script for it to generate in my google sheet.  I cant seem to put the link in the message

`+ ' \n' + itemResponses[39].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[39].getResponse()` this one.

```
// Line Notify
function onFormSubmit() {
 
    var form = FormApp.openById('1ELczQ-uW1mauQrHFBpHK2pQnCCkvPf_4Nq-DPqM4nMw');
    var fRes = form.getResponses();

    var formResponse = fRes[fRes.length - 1];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   
    var msg = 'Electric Forklift Incentive'
     + ' \n' + itemResponses[5].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[5].getResponse()
     + ' \n' + itemResponses[0].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[0].getResponse()
     + ' \n' + itemResponses[1].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[1].getResponse() 
     + ' \n' + itemResponses[2].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[2].getResponse() 
     + ' \n' + itemResponses[3].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[3].getResponse()
     + ' \n' + itemResponses[4].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[4].getResponse()
       + ' \n' + itemResponses[39].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[39].getResponse()
   
        sendLineNotify(msg);

}
function sendLineNotify(message) {

    var token = ["DdiU5tUykpSRpxRVqmEnM7ul3hcE3NEvc6Vzwknyzo7"];
    var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "payload": "message=" + message,
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
        }
    };

    UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", options);
}
```

Comment: At least one of the `itemResponses` indexes doesn't exist in the array.

Comment: ^^ yeah, `console.log` `itemResponses` to see what's missing and debug from there.

Comment: you use array index 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... and then 39 - perhaps itemRepsonses only has 39 items init

Comment: My link that I'm trying to put in the message is not from the form its in my google sheets which i wrote a script to generate it(it in colum 40).

Comment: Why aren't you getting your responses from the trigger's event object?

Comment: Hi there @ThanakornSairat! Please share the logged `itemResponses` to help you better.